# Chinese remainder theorem limits

Tags: number-theory

Is there any solution to $X \equiv ai\ (\textrm{mod}\ qi) $
where $1<i<n$
using CRT and restricting the size of X to be in a range 
$ai< X < b$

Where b is any integer.

I am trying to find a way to reduce the size of X using CRT

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It a solution exists then by CRT any interval of length $ \ge n := {\rm lcm}(q_i)\,$ contains at least one solution, since if $\,x\,$ is a solution then so too is $\, x' = x + nk,\,$ for any integer $\,k;\ $ indeed $\,x'\equiv x\pmod{q_i}\ $ by $\,q_i\mid n.\ $ Shorter intervals need not contain any solution.

Answer (score 0):

No. Firstly, we can just take $b < ai$ so that there are no such $X$ anyway. Intuitively, taking $b$ near $ai$ would also be very limiting, since the CRT only guarantees one solution (and thus any restriction will cause cases where there are no solution).

For instance, consider $a = 3, q = 7$ and $i = 1,2$. Then we want both
$ X \equiv 3 \pmod 7$ and $X \equiv 6 \pmod {14}$. It's clear that the solution is just $X \equiv 6 \pmod {14}$, but then $X \not > 6$. This fails your lower inequality.

Comment: I am little confused. 7 and 14 have to be co-primes. maybe I should say is it possible with the greatest $qi <= X <= b$. so is it possible to have X closer to the largest $qi$ .